# MVC looping in razor, generated dropdownlist not value selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a loop in razor which generates a template a number of times. Inside the template there is a dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownlistFor(x=>x.pasajero[i].option, Model.optionItems)
```

The dropdownlist is rendered, however no option is set with the `selected="selected"` attribute.

I have been able to properly render the dropdownlist outside a loop using same values.
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
@Html.DropDownlistFor(x => x.pasajero[i].option,new SelectList(Model.optionItems,"IdField","DisplayField", Model.pasajero[i].option))
```

Make sure `x.pasajero[i].option` has the same type as `IdField`.

Comment: @ManuelValle: Sorry, it should be `Model`, not `x`. Corrected.

Comment: Do you happen to know why the overload to SelectList is required within a loop, but not normally?