# Dynamic Dropdown not having value pre selected

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a set of dropdowns which are dynamically added by looping a list:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Model.WindowGlassItems.Count; i++)
{

@Html.DropDownListFor(gu => gu.WindowGlassItems[i], Model.WindowGlassTypes, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control glass-multi-select", id = "Glass" + i })


}
```

WindowGlassItems is of type `List<int?>`
The dropdown is not showing the selected item even though this list is set with values

what the issue?

EDIT, currently using this hack, which works but im not happy with, Still would prefer a proper MVC solution if possible

```
@Html.Hidden("HiddenWindowGlassItems", string.Join(",", Model.WindowGlassItems.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray()))
```

JS:

```
var glassCSV = $("#HiddenWindowGlassItems").val();
    if (glassCSV != null) {
        var array = glassCSV.split(',');

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            $("#Glass" + i + " option[value='" + array[i] + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
        }

    }
```

FYI

The selects have names like this:
WindowGlassItems[0]

```
<select name="WindowGlassItems[0]" id="Glass0" data-val-number="The field Nullable`1 must be a number." data-val="true" class="form-control glass-multi-select"><option value="">-- Select --</option>
<option value="637">Tint</option>
etc...

<select name="WindowGlassItems[1]" id="Glass1" data-val-number="The field Nullable`1 must be a number." data-val="true" class="form-control glass-multi-select"><option value="">-- Select --</option>
<option value="637">Tint</option>
etc...
```

and so on...

Comment: I think, it should be like this -  **@Html.DropDownListFor(gu => gu.WindowGlassItems[i], new SelectList(Model.WindowGlassTypes, "Id", "YourGlassItemName", YourSelectedVal), new { @class = "form-control glass-multi-select", id = "Glass" + i })**

Comment: Show us how you assigned values to Model.WindowGlassTypes.

Comment: Model.WindowGlassTypes is of type List<SelectListItem>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end this worked:

(this answer helped: [MVC looping in razor, generated dropdownlist not value selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269411/mvc-looping-in-razor-generated-dropdownlist-not-value-selected) )

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.WindowGlassUnitsCount; i++)
{

         @Html.DropDownListFor(gu => gu.WindowGlassItems[i],
         new SelectList(Model.WindowGlassTypes,"Value","Text", Model.WindowGlassItems[i]),

         //Model.WindowGlassTypes,

         "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control glass-multi-select", id = "Glass" + i })


}
```

Answer (score 2):

`DropDownListFor` doesn't get the selected Value anywhere. The expression `go => go.WindowGlassItems[i]` just specifies the Model-Mapping (Name and Id of the Html-Element get generated here)

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.WindowGlassItems.Count; i++)
{

    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        gu => gu.WindowGlassItems[i], // This is the selected value.
        new SelectList(Model.WindowGlassTypes, Model.WindowGlassItems[i])
        "-- Select --", 
        new { @class = "form-control glass-multi-select", id = "Glass" + i })
}
```

pass the selected value with `new SelectList()`

Comment: To do this... the `WindowGlassTypes` must be a collection of items... not of type `SelectList`. And in the SelectList constructor, I think it is better to define the property that holds Text and Value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have pre selected item, your Model.WindowGlassTypes collection must be of type IList. System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem has a boolean property Selected, that you will need to set to true to an element that you want to be selected.

Comment: WindowGlassTypes  is List<SelectListItem>, usually you dont need to set this boolean value?

Comment: You have to specify which one is selected from my experience with the helper.